# Flutter Firebase Dynamic Link is either null or does not return the complete URL

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I have been trying to implement deep linking on my flutter app. I am using [Firebase Dynamic Links Package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) for this feature. The main problem i get from this is that it only returns for me the base url.

The link i tap on to trigger the link is from the backend and its something like this:

https://share.app.io/my-custom-url?token=eZhOa9jIXhTuisoaJ1v

I need this same link returned for me from the listener but it only returns the host which is share.app.io. Sometimes, it returns as null too.

**My Code**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  FirebaseDynamicLinks dynamicLinks = FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    initDynamicLinks();
  }
  Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData? data =
    await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri? deepLink = data?.link;
    print("dynamic link data " + deepLink.toString());
    dynamicLinks.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) {

      Navigator.push(
        navigatorKey.currentState!.context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                ProfilePage()),
      );
    }).onError((error) {
      print('onLink error');
      print(error.message);
    });
  }
}
```

How do i get the dynamic link to return the correct and complete link containing all parameters when tapped on it from a browser?

Comment: Hi, did you find out what to do with it?